# Split producing an array of lines rather than paragraphs

Tags: arrays, powershell, split

I'm attempting to divide a string into paragraphs with the dividing line being between occurrences of the characters "/*".Currently using the split function creates an array where each element is a new line of the text instead of whole paragraphs. In the code below which I'm currently using I have escaped the * but it appears that I'm still missing something. Thanks.

```bsh
$scripts = $allScripts -split "/\*"
```

Expected output:

```
$scripts[0] = "ABC
DEF
GHI"
```

Actual output:

```
$scripts[0] = "ABC"
$scripts[1] = "DEF"
$scripts[2] = "GHI"
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: What if you try ```$allScripts -replace "/\*","`n"```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem, the issue was actually with the Get-Content method to read the file as this produces an array rather than a string.

This was solved by casting the array into a string:

```
$scripts = ("$allScripts") -split [Regex]::Escape("/*")
```

This produced an additional side effect by removing all newline characters resulting in a single continuous block of text. This was fixed by adding the -raw parameter to Get-Content:

```
$allScripts = Get-Content -Path $file -Raw
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join from the string library, to join by the newline character:

```
> [String]::Join("`n", $allScripts -split "/\*")
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

This is general purpose, for concatenating `string[]` to a single multi-line string.

However, in this specific case [@AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960501/split-producing-an-array-of-lines-rather-than-paragraphs#comment102333162_57960501) has the more elegant solution, replacing your special new line characters, with the actual new line character:

```
> $allScripts -replace "/\*", "`n"
ABC
DEF
GHI
```